# How do I parse normal feeds with DocPad Plugin Feedr?

Tags: parsing, feed, docpad

I can't figure out how to use [feedr](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-feedr) to parse a normal rss-feed like http://mashable.com/feed/.

How do I parse the feed? The documentation is quite poor. The twitter-example doesn't help me. For example I would like to grab a feed and show its content in a way like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="link-to-posting">Post Title</a> – Post Content</li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feedr plugin just turns any json or xml into a javascript object that you can use in pages.  So with RSS feeds, you'll end up with an object that has properties that match the [XML in the rss](http://mashable.com/feed/) feed with elements becoming objects, etc.  So there will be a channel object and then under that an array of item objects, etc...

Here's how your mashable example would work.  Put this in the docpad.coffee configuration:

```
plugins:
    feedr:
        feeds:
            mashable:
                url: 'http://mashable.com/feed/'
```

Then, you can use the `@feedr.feeds.mashable` object in a page like this:

```
<ul>
    <% for item in @feedr.feeds.mashable.channel.item: %>
        <li><a href="<%= item.link %>"><%= item.title %></a> - <%- item.description %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did it the same way as you did except `@feedr.feeds.phlow.channel.item` That did the trick. Now it's working.

Comment: Right.  `phlow` or `mashable` will be whatever you named it in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else got trouble parsing... If you like to include a title, description and link to the parsed feed, add this snippet. This will add a linked title plus description.

```
<h1><a href="<%- @feedr.feeds.mashable.channel.link %>"><%= @feedr.feeds.mashable.channel.title %></a></h1>
<p><%= @feedr.feeds.mashable.channel.description %></p>
```

And than the rest like Erv mentioned above.

```
<ul>
    <% for item in @feedr.feeds.mashable.channel.item: %>
        <li><a href="<%= item.link %>"><%= item.title %></a> - <%- item.description %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```